# Display the name instead of the ID

Tags: php, mysql

Database setup:

Table: customers

```
id | name | address | zipcode | city | phone | email | active
```

Table: todo

```
id | customerid | description | information | active


$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM todo
  ORDER 
    BY `customerid` ASC
     , `description` ASC
";
```

show results:

```
echo $row['customerid'] $row['description'] $row['information'];
```

output:

```
customerid description information
```

desired output:

```
customername (from table customers) description information
```

I have been reading this forum and i find that i should use INNER JOIN but i can't get it to work.

Could anyone assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,you need use `join` to get the customername value

```
SELECT t.description,t.information,c.name 
    FROM todo t JOIN customers c ON c.id=t.customerid 
ORDER BY `t.customerid` ASC, `description` ASC
```

Then try with below:

```
echo $row['name'] $row['description'] $row['information'];
```

Comment: Dear, 

With those 2 lines i dont get any output anymore. It's empty :(

Comment: you need check your table data or use `left join` instead of `join`

Comment: SELECT t.description,t.information,c.customername 
FROM todo t LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.customerid=t.customerid 
ORDER BY `customerid` ASC, `description` ASC LIMIT 0, 25
#1054 - Unknown column 'c.customername' in field list

Comment: then `customername` is not in table `customers`,you need add more information about your question

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

I provided the tables setup above. 
there is indeed no customersname, in that table it's just the 'name'. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is when you use "ORDER BY" you can't use the "*". Here is how your code should go:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT customers.customerid,name, description, information FROM  customers INNER JOIN todo ON customers.customerid=todo.customerid ORDER 
BY customers.customerid ASC
 , description ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>". $row["name"]." ".$row["description"]. " " . $row["information"] . "<br>";
 }
 } else {
echo "0 results";
 }

 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

This should do it.